# How to manage a CancelledError in an Event loop with asyncio and python?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am trying to use a python file to handle all requests sent by a bot to a server via API. According to their documentation, the use of asyncio is recommended. Here is my code below :

```py
import asyncio
import websockets
import json
import sys
import time
from datetime import datetime
import threading

from config.private.deribit_config import *

class DeribitWssApi_BotScalp(object):
    def __init__(self, client_id, secret, private_endpoint, public_endpoint):
        self.client_id = client_id
        self.client_secret = secret
        self.private_url = private_endpoint
        self.public_url = public_endpoint
        self.json = {
            "jsonrpc" : "2.0",
            "id" : 1,
            "method" : None,
        }
        self.auth_json = {
            "jsonrpc" : "2.0",
            "id" : 9929,
            "method" : "public/auth",
        }

        self.logout_json = {
            "jsonrpc" : "2.0",
            "id": 42,
            "method" : "private/logout",
        }
        self.expiration = datetime.now().timestamp()
        self.token = None

    # send an authentication request
    async def private_api(self, request):
        #Adding delay to not overload the API server
        #await asyncio.sleep(0.25)

        #Initiate a private connection to the server
        async with websockets.connect(self.private_url) as websocket:
            
            # Check if the authentication token must be refreshed
            if (datetime.now().timestamp() >= self.expiration) or (self.token == None):
                options = {
                    "grant_type" : "client_credentials",
                    "client_id" : self.client_id,
                    "client_secret" : self.client_secret
                }
                self.auth_json["params"] = options

                #Send connection credentials
                await websocket.send(json.dumps(self.auth_json))
                while websocket.open:
                    _response = await websocket.recv()
                    _response = json.loads(_response)
                    self.expiration += _response["result"]["expires_in"]
                    self.token = _response["result"]["access_token"]
                    break

            #Send API request
            await websocket.send(request)
            while websocket.open:
                response = await websocket.recv()
                response = json.loads(response)
                break


            #logout gracefully
            _options = {
                "access_token" : self.token,
                "invalidate_token" : True
            }
            #use try/except structure to not be blocked by "successful ws closed" exception
            try:
                self.logout_json["params"] = _options
                self.token = None
                await websocket.send(json.dumps(self.logout_json))
                while websocket.open:
                    _response = await websocket.recv()
                    _response = json.loads(_response)
                    break
                    
            except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedOK as e:
                pass

            return response

    # send a public method request
    async def public_api(self, request):
        #Adding delay to not overload the API server
        #await asyncio.sleep(0.075)

        #Sending the request directly
        async with websockets.connect(self.public_url) as websocket:
            await websocket.send(request)
            while websocket.open:
                response = await websocket.recv()
                response = json.loads(response)
                return response

    # create an asyncio event loop
    def loop(self, api, request):
        response = ""
        try:
            response = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(api(json.dumps(request)))
        except RuntimeError as ex:
            if "There is no current event loop in thread" in str(ex):
                new_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
                asyncio.set_event_loop(new_loop)
                response = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(api(json.dumps(request)))
        return response
```

Without touching anything, I encounter the CancelledError exception at some point, it can range from 5 minutes of use to 1 day. Surprisingly, I can have 2 different tracebacks when it happens. I usually have both when I run 2 instances of the same bot in parallel.

**Error message #1**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/websockets/legacy/client.py", line 655, in __await_impl_timeout__
    return await self.__await_impl__()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/websockets/legacy/client.py", line 659, in __await_impl__
    _transport, _protocol = await self._create_connection()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1081, in create_connection
    transport, protocol = await self._create_connection_transport(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1111, in _create_connection_transport
    await waiter
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError
```

**Error message #2**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/websockets/legacy/client.py", line 655, in __await_impl_timeout__
    return await self.__await_impl__()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/websockets/legacy/client.py", line 659, in __await_impl__
    _transport, _protocol = await self._create_connection()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1041, in create_connection
    sock = await self._connect_sock(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 955, in _connect_sock
    await self.sock_connect(sock, address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 502, in sock_connect
    return await fut
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError
```

From my understanding, there is a trick where I should use `asyncio.gather()` but I do not explicitly use task, but an event loop. So, I don't know how to debug this :(

I tried to wrap the API communication functions with a try/except structure, but it seems like it is not invoked.
I tried to position my await `asyncio.sleep()` functions at different positions to allow some time for the API calls to be completely performed, I haven't found a trick to solve this.

High-level speaking, I have the intuition that asyncio is trying to access a task that doesn't exist. But "code speaking", I don't know how to verify and solve it.